# Monitor to laptop DVI to HDMI connection not working

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I have Samsung B2330 monitor with VGA and DVI and my laptop is dell XPS 15 9750 with Intel UHD 630 graphics card. I try to connect it to the laptop with DVI to HDMI converter like [this](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0672/9409/products/11431108_grande.jpg?v=1537174782).

The laptop detects the screen but the monitor shows nothing but `(Check Signal Cable)`. Whenever I plug and unplug the HDMI into my laptop, the monitor refreshes but keeps the no signal message.

I tried the same cable configuration on an old HP laptop with Intel HD graphics card and it worked fine. I can't figure the problem in my Dell XPS laptop

Comment: What happens when you ask if to scan for new monitors?

Comment: can't understand your can you explain more please

Comment: Settings, display  https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2fPm.png on windows 11

Comment: no my monitor is detected successfully  by the laptop but the monitor itself shows nothing if you are asking for another reason when i press detect it shows (we didn't find another display)

Comment: Are you outputing the correct settings for the monitor in your HDMI port (resolution, vertical and horizontal frecuency, color depth...). If the laptot detects the screen I'm assuming you can change its settings from there.